# Wordpress popularity contest to only track posts from a specific category

Tags: wordpress

I am using popularity contest for wordpress in a self-hosted website.

Is it possible to the popularity contest only track the posts from a specific category?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though I haven't worked with popularity-contest in a little while, I think this should work:

```
/**
 * Define the categories to be tracked
 */
$GLOBALS['pc_track_cats'] = array(1,3,5,8); // alternately, category slugs can be used as well

/**
 * Check the content each time it is called to see if we're in our target cat
 * if not, remove the popularity-contest filter
 *
 * @param string $the_content
 * @return string
 */
function my_check_pc($the_content) {
    if (!in_category($GLOBALS['pc_track_cats'])) {
        remove_filter('the_content', 'akpc_content_pop');
    }
    return $the_content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'my_check_pc', 1);

/**
 * Replace the popularity contest filter after the content has been run
 *
 * @param string $the_content
 * @return string
 */
function my_replace_pc($the_content) {
    add_filter('the_content', 'akpc_content_pop');
    return $the_content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'my_replace_pc', 9999);
```